# How to pass HTML string from flask app to HTML template as a DOM element and then appendChild

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, flask

**CONTEXT**

I've created a Flask web app that has a form on the webpage, and then I want the user to see the results of that form immediately to the right of the form. When the form is submitted, a python script is activated on the backend, and this produces an HTML result file (`authorList.html`) - which is what I want to display next to the form.

**PROBLEM**

From what I understand, this requires me to use Ajax, so I can get results without refreshing the page, but I'm not as familiar with how to pass that HTML result file from the flask app.py to the HTML template and then append that as a node to the DOM tree.

1) I have my code set up so far such that the `upload` route is invoked, which then renders `index.html`, and then the JS code in there refers back to the `results` route, which then renders `index.html` again, passing in the HTML result file as a string. I've partially set up the HTML-string-to-DOM-element conversion step in `index.html` under where it says `<p>Results should display here.</p>` (as this is the part of the page where I want the HTML result file to display) but am not sure if I'm on the right track and how to proceed with doing appendchild.

2) Also, when I try running this code below the way it is, I get a JS error of `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;` pointing to this line of `index.html`: `var d = document.createElement('div'); d.innerHTML = ; return d.firstChild;`...is it because I'm not passing in the `data` variable correctly on the Flask app side? **(RESOLVED AND UPDATED IN CODE ACCORDINGLY)**

(note: I am not familiar with JS, so if this seems simple, I apologize in advance!)

**SOURCE CODE**

**app.py:**

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    return render_template('index.html', template_file=app.config['TEMPLATE_FILE'])


@app.route("/results", methods=['POST'])
def results():
    data = []
    if request.method == 'POST':
            if request.form['affiliation'] == "letter":
                affiliation = "let"
            elif request.form['affiliation'] == "number":
                affiliation = "num"

            proc = subprocess.Popen('python author_script.py {} -p {} -s {} -m {}'.format(file.filename, period, space, affiliation), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
            while proc.poll() is None:
                time.sleep(0.5)

            # Convert resulting HTML file to a string and pass to index.html
            with open('authorList.html') as f:
                data.append("".join(f.readlines()))
    return render_template('index.html', data=''.join(data))
```

**index.html:**

```
<html>

<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('form').submit(function (e) {
            var url = "{{ url_for('results') }}"; 
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: $('form').serialize(), 
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data) 
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault(); 
        });
    });
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div>
            <br>
            <p>Download the template file below and re-upload with your custom author information:</p>
            <a href="static/ExampleAuthorList.txt" download="Authors_Template.txt"><button type="button">Download</button></a><br><br>
            <form action="" id="myform" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
            <div id="buttonDiv">
              <p><input type=file name=file value="Choose File">
              <p>Mark affiliations with:</p>
              <input type="radio" name="affiliation" value="number" id="number" class="form-radio" checked><label for="number">Number</label><br>
              <input type="radio" name="affiliation" value="letter" id="letter" class="form-radio"><label for="letter">Letter</label>
              <br><br>
            </div>
            <input type=submit value=Upload></p>
            </form>
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div>
          <p>Results should display here.</p>
          <script>
            var d = document.createElement('div'); d.innerHTML = "{{ data }}"; return d.firstChild;
            # Need code for appending child
          </script>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

**UPDATE**

I tried the following change in my JS code (in `index.html`) but am still not seeing any results appear on the homepage.

```
  <script>
    var data 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('form').submit(function (e) {
            var url = "{{ url_for('results') }}"; // send the form data here.
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: url,
              data: $('form').serialize(), 
              success: function (data) {
                var d = document.createElement('div');
                d.innerHTML = data;
                $(".my-results").html(data);
              }
            });
            e.preventDefault(); // block the traditional submission of the form.
        });
    });
</script>

.
.
.
.
        <div>
          <br>
          <p class="my-results">Results should display here.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**UPDATE 2: full app.py**

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    return render_template('index.html', template_file=app.config['TEMPLATE_FILE'])

@app.route("/results", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def results():
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        flash('No file chosen', 'danger')
        return redirect(request.url)
    file = request.files['file']
    if file.filename == '':
        flash('No selected file', 'danger')
        return redirect(request.url)
    filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
    if not allowed_file(file.filename):
        flash('Incorrect file extension. Must be .TXT!', 'danger')
    if places_exist(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)) == False:
        flash('There is an affiliation missing from your Place list. Please re-try.', 'danger')
        return redirect(request.url)
    else:
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))

        os.chdir('/Users/cdastmalchi/Desktop/author_script/')

        if request.form['affiliation'] == "letter":
            affiliation = "let"
        elif request.form['affiliation'] == "number":
            affiliation = "num"

        if "Yes sep period" in request.form.getlist('period'):
            period = "y"
        else:
            period = "n"
        if "Yes sep space" in request.form.getlist('space'):
            space = "y"
        else:
            space = "n"

        proc = subprocess.Popen('python author_script.py {} -p {} -s {} -m {}'.format(file.filename, period, space, affiliation), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        # Wait until process terminates
        while proc.poll() is None:
            time.sleep(0.5)

        with open("authorList.html") as f:
            data = ''.join(f.readlines())
            print(data)
        return data
```

Comment: The trouble is that the returned value, `data`, in the `success` handler of the `$.ajax` request is actually your entire `index.html` file again. Is `data` in the `ajax` request scope supposed to be storing the value of `''.join(data)`, created on the Python side?

Comment: @Ajax1234, yes so how I'd like it is to have `success` in the `$.ajax` return the value of `' '.join(data)` from the python side (which is the form's html result that I want to display on the same page).

Comment: Ok, just one more thing: `file` is not defined in `app.py`, can you clarify?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry that is in my `results` route, for which I did not include the full function initially, but it's all there now in Update 2!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To upload a file dynamically, you need to use the `FormData` object in Javascript with a `POST` request. This solution sends two separate requests: the `POST` request with the file data, and a `GET` request with the additional values. The filename is stored in `flask.session` to be used in the context of the `GET` request when the final data is computed:

First, in your `app.py`, you need three routes: a route to render `index.html`, a route to handle the file data, and lastly, a route to return the html:

`app.py`:

```
import flask, string, random
import json
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in range(20)) #needed to use flask.session
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home():
   return flask.render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/process_file', methods=['POST'])
def process_file():
  #here, you can run all the checks as before, but instead of flash, you can return jsonified results to read in the front-end
  if 'file' not in flask.request.files or not flask.request.files['file'].filename:
     return flask.jsonify({'result':'False', 'message':'no files selected'})
  file = flask.request.files['file']
  filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
  if not allowed_file(file.filename):
     return flask.jsonify({'result':'False', 'message':'Must be TXT file!'})
  if not places_exist(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)):
     return flask.jsonify({'result':'False', 'message':'There is an affiliation missing from your Place list. Please re-try.'})
  file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
  flask.session['filename'] = filename
  return flask.jsonify({'result':'True'})

@app.route('/upload_vals')
def upload_vals():
  payload = json.loads(flask.request.args.get('payload'))
  #do something with payload
  #payload will now be in the form:
  #{'affiliation':'Number', 'period':'no', 'space':'yes'}
  proc = subprocess.Popen('python author_script.py {} -p {} -s {} -m {}'.format(flask.session['filename'], 'y' if _checked['period'] else 'n', 'y' if _checked['space'] else 'n', aff[:3]), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  while proc.poll() is None:
     time.sleep(0.5)
  with open("authorList.html") as f:
    data = ''.join(f.readlines())
  return flask.jsonify({'data':data})
```

`index.html`:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
    <div class='wrapper'>
      <p>Download the template file below and re-upload with your custom author information:</p>
      <a href="static/ExampleAuthorList.txt" download="Authors_Template.txt"><button type="button">Download</button></a><br><br>
        <form action="" id="myform" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
        <input type=file name=file value="Choose File">
           <p class='error_message'></p>
        </form>
         <div id="buttonDiv"> 
            <p>Mark affiliations with:</p> 
            <input type="radio" name="affiliation" value="number" data-key='affiliation' data-value='number' class="form-radio main_checkbox" checked><label for="number">Number</label><br> 
            <input type="radio" name="affiliation" value="letter" data-key='affiliation' data-value='letter' class="form-radio main_checkbox"><label for="letter">Letter</label><br> 
           <p>Separate initials with period:</p> 
           <input type="radio" name="period" value="separated" data-key='period' data-value='yes' class="form-radio period"><label for="period">Yes</label><br> 
           <input type="radio" name="period" data-key='period' data-value='no' value="separated" class="form-radio period" checked><label for="period">No</label> 
           <br> 
           <p>Separate initials with space:</p> 
           <input type="radio" name="space" value="separated" data-key='space' data-value='yes' class="form-radio spacing"><label for="space">Yes</label><br> 
           <input type="radio" name="space" data-key='space' data-value='no' value="separated" class="form-radio spacing" checked><label for="space">No</label><br> 
          <br><br> 
         </div> 
        <button class='submit_data'>Submit</button>
        <div>
         <br>
         <p class="my-results"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.wrapper').on('click', '.submit_data', function(){
             var form_data = new FormData($('#myform')[0]);
             var flag = true;
             $.ajax({
               type: 'POST',
               url: '/process_file',
               data: form_data,
               contentType: false,
               cache: false,
               processData: false,
               success: function(data) {
                 if (data.result === 'False'){
                    $('.error_message').html(data.message)
                    flag = false;
                 }
              },
           });
           if (flag){
             var payload = {};
             $('.form-radio').each(function(){
                if ($(this).prop('checked')){
                  payload[$(this).data('key')] = $(this).data('value');
                }
             });
             $.ajax({
               url: "/upload_vals",
               type: "get",
               data: {'payload':JSON.stringify(payload)},
               success: function(response) {
                 $(".my-results").html(response.data);
               },
              });
           }
        });
      });
    </script>
</html>
```

---

It is slightly unclear in your updated `app.py` where the `period` and `space` form values originate from in the HTML, however, in the the `index.html` above, two additional checkboxes are provided to receive this value from the user.

Comment: Thanks very much for your response! I'm trying this out now and think I'm close. However, I'm getting `Keyerror: 'filename'` pointing to the line in `upload_vals()` where it's called. I've tried printing `flask.session`, but that's not working either.

Comment: @claudiadast Hmm. Can you verify that the file is being uploaded correctly by adding a `print(flask.session['filename'])` just after `flask.session['filename'] = filename` in `process_file`? If nothing is printed out when you run it again, then that means one of the file validation checks failed.

Comment: Tried that and indeed nothing is printing out :/ Also, when I check the javascript console, it says: `jquery.min.js:5 POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/uploadajax 404 (NOT FOUND),
jquery.min.js:5 GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/upload_vals?affiliation=number&checked=%7B%22period%22%3Afalse%2C%22space%22%3Afalse%7D 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)" `

Comment: @claudiadast Ok, can you print out `'file' in flask.request.files` just below the `process_file` declaration? Please let me know what result is returned.

Comment: @claudiadast My apologies, the first `ajax` request had the wrong URL. Please try now with the updated `index.html`. Sorry!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192592/discussion-between-claudiadast-and-ajax1234).

Answer (score 1):

To fix your syntax error put quotes around `{{ data }}`.

```
d.innerHTML = "{{ data }}";
```

Without the quotes the result is

```
d.innerHTML = ;
```

But don't worry because you need to move that code anyway.

The JavaScript in the second `<script>` tag doesn't know about the `data` because it is out of scope.  You need to move that code into your `$.ajax` success method.  This should work better:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: $('form').serialize(), 
  success: function (data) {
    var d = document.createElement('div');
    d.innerHTML = data;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your input! So after adding `data` to the ajax method, I'm assuming I then do the `appendChild()` part in the second script tag? How do I make that connection?

Comment: You want to do all of that inside of the success method.  That second code bock will not have any of your other variables in scope.

Comment: Ah I see. But then if I do that how would I be able to specify where on the homepage I want the HTML element to load? (which is what the point of that second script tag was, since it's in a column 'div' that specifies the right side of the page)

Comment: Try adding a class to `<p class="my-results">Results should display here.</p>`

Then use jQuery to inject it:
`$(".my-results").html(data)`

Comment: I tried implementing this solution (see update above) !