# Flask Web App: Filter table view by button

Tags: python, html, mysql, flask

I would like to be able to filter the table in this html page by button, i.e domain. Check here [Html View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhQUg.png). For example if someone clicks on photographer only photographers show up.

Flask function:

```
@app.route('/find_artist',methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def find_artist():
    if session.get("email"):
        if request.method == 'GET':
            return render_template('find_artist.html')
        curl = mysql.connection.cursor()
        curl.execute("SELECT * FROM freelancers")
        data = curl.fetchall()
        curl.close()
        return render_template(
            "find_artist.html",
            freelancers=data)
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

HTML code for buttons and table:

```
<div id="myBtnContainer">
  <button class="btn active" > Show all</button>
  <button class="btn" > Illustrator</button>
  <button class="btn"> Animator</button>
  <button class="btn" > Digital Designer</button>
  <button class="btn">Photographer</button>
  <button class="btn"> Filmmaker</button>
  <button class="btn"> Graphic Design</button>
  </div>

    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Serial</th>
          <th scope="col">First Name </th>
          <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Email</th>
          <th scope="col">Domain</th>
          <th scope="col">Experience</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="myTable">
        {% for item in freelancers %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{item["id"]}}</td>
          <td>{{item["first_name"]}}</td>
          <td>{{item["last_name"]}}</td>
          <td>{{item["email"]}}</td>
          <td>{{item["domain"]}}</td>
          <td>{{item["experience"]}}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution that worked for me is to create a separate endpoint for each button.

```
def multiple_buttons(condition):
    if session.get("email"):
        curl = mysql.connection.cursor()
        curl.execute("SELECT * FROM freelancers WHERE domain LIKE %s", [condition])
        data = curl.fetchall()
        curl.close()
        return render_template(
            "find_artist.html",
            freelancers=data)
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))

@app.route('/showall',methods=['POST'])
def showall():
    return multiple_buttons(None)


@app.route('/illustrator',methods=['POST'])
def illustrator():
    return multiple_buttons('Illustrator')
```

HTML :

```
<form action="/showall" method="post" style="display:inline-block">
      <button class="btn active" name="showall"  type="submit"> Show All</button>
  </form>
  <form action="/illustrator" method="post" style="display:inline-block">
      <button class="btn" name="illustrator"  type="submit"> Illustrator</button>
  </form>
```

This answer was very helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42859886/8131701