# Problem with Ajax and flask, what is the problem?

Tags: python, jquery, flask

i want comunicate the views with backend from ajax, i am trying but not show in console the message of backend "HELLO", what is the problem?

```
       <script type=text/javascript>
        $(function() {
          $('a#test').bind('click', function() {
            $.getJSON('/background_process_test',
                function(data) {
              //do nothing
            });
            return false;
          });
        });
</script>
//button
<div class='container'>
    <h3>Test</h3>
        <form>
            <a href=# id=test><button class='btn btn-default'>Test</button></a>
        </form>

</div>
```

My backend is this, i am use framework flask

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, support_credentials=True)


@app.route('/background_process_test')
@cross_origin(supports_credentials=True)
def background_process_test():
    print "Hello"
    return "nothing"   



if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000, debug=True)


@app.route("/login")
@cross_origin(supports_credentials=True)
def login():
  return jsonify({'success': 'ok'})
```

this error i get:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///background_process_test' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

Comment: put your function before `app.run()` (and before `if __name__ == "__main__":)`

Comment: don't you get any error message when you run flask in console/terminal/cmd.exe ? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: @furas 
no there is no error, the server just listens, use a WSGI production server instead.
* Debug mode: activated
* Runs at http://0.0.0.0:8000/ (Press CTRL + C to exit)
* Restart with stat
* The debugger is active!
* Debugger PIN: 277-757-720

Comment: do you get `'GGG'` in browser's console when you click `'a#test'` on page ? If it runs AJAX code and it tries to connect to flask then it should display error because it couldn't find `@app.route('/background_process_test')`

Comment: i am using this code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42601478/flask-calling-python-function-on-button-onclick-event of @Gihan Gamage but now i get this error Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///background_process_test' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: do you changed code in question ? why ? did you test new code ? maybe it works correctly.

Comment: @furas 
I want to know why the code of that answer does not work

Comment: and I want know if you tested new code - maybe it works and you only waist time .

Comment: @furas with this new code now i get this error Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///background_process_test' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: how do you display this html ? I don't see template in your code and there is no full URL in html.  maybe AJAX try to connect to different server.

Comment: if you get error then you should always put it in question. It may change everything. Previously it displayed nothing , now it display error whcih may help to find problem.

Comment: error show problem with credentials. did you try without credentials ?

Comment: I see `'file:///background_process_test'` - did you run HTML from local file ? It may not have privilages to access server. Why don't use use flask to serve this file ?

Comment: in error is also information that file has to use scheme `http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https` and it meas it has to be served from server.

Comment: i know not of credentials, is all that code, or ajax is bad?

Comment: bad is that you don't serve HTML from server - and then it blocks access to function in flask. All for security reason.

Comment: mmm i am new in flask, how can i solved this, create your answer please

Comment: You have to create function which use `return render_template("your_file.html")`. [flask documentation](https://palletsprojects.com/p/flask/). By the way: you have it in you link with code which you use. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42601478/flask-calling-python-function-on-button-onclick-event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After all there was two problems:

- HTML wasn't serve from flask/server. And browser could block it for security reason. I put HTML directly in function `index()` but later you can use `render_template("filename.html")`
- you forgot to load javascript `jQuery` library.

In code from your link both elements exists - so you should have already working code: [Flask - Calling python function on button OnClick event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42601478/flask-calling-python-function-on-button-onclick-event)

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin


app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, support_credentials=True)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return """
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type=text/javascript>
   $(function() {
     $('a#sender').bind('click', function() {
       $.getJSON('/background_process_test',
         function(data) {
           console.log(data);
           window.alert(data['success'])  
         });
       return false; // stop <a> to send normal request
     });
   });
</script>

<form>
    <a href=# id="sender"><button>Send AJAX</button></a>
</form>

</div>"""

@app.route('/background_process_test')
@cross_origin(supports_credentials=True)
def background_process_test():
    print("Hello AJAX")
    return jsonify({'success': 'OK'})


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```