# Request data in Flask each time when clicking the button in HTML

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm new for flask and HTML. I want an application that each time I click a button, the web can request data from the dataset in flask.
For example, there is a dataset in flask like

`[{'col0': 0,'col1': 0,'col2': 0},{'col0': 1,'col1': 1,'col2': 1},{'col0': 2,'col1': 2,'col2': 2},{'col0': 3,'col1': 3,'col2': 3}]`

I want to make a button such that every time I click the button, the web can extract two dicts in the dataset and append them in the table in HTML. What should I do? Sorry I don't have codes now because I don't where to start. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO, and welcome to the Flask world too. Can you share the code you have tried, what you got stuck with or the error you are facing?

Comment: Sorry I don't have codes now because I don't where to start .

Comment: I would recommend going through the [Tutorial on Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/tutorial/), that's where I started. It may not answer your question right away but I can assure you that you'll know how to do what your require by the end of the tutorial!

Comment: From your browser-side/frontend codes, you need to make a GET request to your server-side/backend Flask app, handle that request, and send back a response, and render in HTML. You can use Flask templates to create your frontend or learn any of the popular frontend (JS) frameworks.

Comment: Here is one of the results after searching with the keywords in my previous comment: [Flask - Calling python function on button OnClick event](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42601478/2745495)